# Simple Android App Stopped Error

Tags: android, android-intent

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button me = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        me.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent page = new Intent(view.getContext(),Activity2.class);
                startActivityForResult(page,0);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }


}
```

Activity2

```
public class Activity2 extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.myinfo);
    }
}
```

In the activity_main.xml,i have created a button.I want to open a new activity myinfo which has some text.But when i press the button it shows me an error "Unfortunately,Application has Stopped".What am i supposed to do.I have read i need to read the log but it is quiet complicated there.How can i debug? I am using the android Studio.

Comment: is Activity2 declared inside the AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: no,it is not.Why does it have to be declared?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use startActivity instead of startactivityforresult. Following is currect way.

```
  me.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent page = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Activity2.class);
                    startActivity(page);
                }
            });
```

And you need to declare Activity2 inside the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

First declare the new activity you added in your manifest file, inside Application Tag, all activities you add in your application must be declared in manifest file.

Secondly, use

```
 Intent i = new Intent(FirstAct.this,SecondAct.class);
                    startActivity(i);
```

To move from first activity to second activity.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Intent page = new Intent(getApplicationcontext,Activity2.class);
 startActivityForResult(page,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get context from view and opening an activity using that context ...It doesn't work that way..you need to pass the context of current Activity or Fragment and then pass it while creating an intent

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,ToNavigateActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```